# virtual method in base class and non virtula method in child class. Still how child class method is called even if its is non-virtual

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions

I was going through a piece of code as mentioned below and found that the method in child class is non-virtual, still the method is getting called by its base class pointer. Can anybody tell me the reason why....??

```
class Base {
    virtual void method() { std::cout << "from Base" << std::endl; }
public:
    virtual ~Base() { method(); }
    void baseMethod() { method(); }
};

class A : public Base {
    void method() { std::cout << "from A" << std::endl; }
public:
    ~A() { method(); }
};


int main(void) {
    Base* base = new A;
    base->baseMethod();     
    getchar();
    return 0;       
}
```

Output - from A

Comment: The `virtual` Keyword is optional in derived classes.

Comment: virtual once - virtual forever... there is no way to "devirtualize" method.

Comment: does that mean virtual keyword in child class is optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in the derived class which overrides the virtual method will be [virtual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) too; it has nothing to with that the keyword `virtual` is used for it or not.

> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration) and overrides Base::vf (whether or not the word override is used in its declaration).

Comment: It would be good to include a reference to where that quotation is from.

Comment: @MartinBonner I put the link on the word "virtual". ?